# Why I can't get the property value passed to component?

Tags: ember.js

I have a component named `star-rate`, it has a `score` property. The code in template is:

```
{{star-rate score=score}}
```

In the *component/star-rate.js*, I wrote:

```
didInsertElement: function() {
  var score = this.get('score');
  console.log(score); // undefined, why?
}
```

Why can't get the score value? But if I change the template code into this:

```
{{star-rate score=4}}
```

then I will get the score value.

Comment: Maybe try {{star-rate score=model.score}} or create a failing emberjs.jsbin.com

Answer (score 0):

I'd say all is fine with the component, but the `score` value you are assigning is `undefined` itself.

Comment: I get score from model, if the model.score=3 and I just write this : <span>The score is: {{model.score}}</span>, and I will get: <span>The score is: 3</span>

Comment: @markduan If `score` is a property on `commentEntry` you have to pass the full path like so: `{{star-rate score=commentEntry.score}}`.

Comment: yes, I do it just like what you said, but still can't get the value, if I write this:{{log 'score' model.score}}, the result is undefined too.

Comment: @markduan Well, since you didn't provide any other details and you keep swapping `score`, `model.score`, and `commentEntry.score`, I assume that you don't know where exactly the score data hangs in the model/controller. Anyway, the component is alright and you are passing it an `undefined` value.

Comment: sorry for my English, and it is too hard for me to explain the context, I will edit the question again when I find the right way.

Answer (score 0):

The component is fine. Try setting score a value on the controller of the template (where you're calling the component.

```
    export default Ember.Controller.extend({
    score:0,
  })
```

It won't be undefined anymore.

Alternatively you can use the setupController property in the template's route.